# SQL Server 2012 Browser Service doesn't appear

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've installed SQL Server 2012 and Management Studio Express. I attached the database that belongs my previous Project in Visual Studio. But I am having SqlException Error , I think the reason of the error is SQL Server. Because when I look at active services, I only  see SQL Server VSS Writer service. I can't see SQL Server Browser Service and other SQL Server services. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you run SQL Server Express, by default, the named instance option is selected with SQLExpress as the instance name. Ab example "SERVER01\SQLEXPRESS".

You should have a browser service but can you give the SQL Exception you're having because this migth have a clue what's going wrong.

Comment: It is : SqlException was unhandled by user code. An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.